# ReactJS: changes in state not recognized inside functions?

Tags: reactjs, state

Suppose I have a `recursive` function that increments a counter, and I'd like to reset this counter upon a user request.

For this, I declared a state variable that would get 'true' when the user requests a reset.

Inside my function, I have a condition checking whether this state variable is true, and if so, does what it does to reset the timer.

Unfortunately, the condition never becomes true as the state change isn't recognized (I double-checked it using the console to make sure).

The same code does work when using a global variable like `window.resetRequested`, or by declaring a variable outside the component function, instead of `state`.

I feel like there's something basic I'm missing here (which makes sense as I'm pretty new to web programming).

```
let timerValue = currentUser.sessionTimeout;

       function createTimer() {
            if (timerResetRequested === true) {
                timerValue = currentUser.sessionTimeout;
            }
    
            if (timerValue === 0) {
                const logOutDate = new Date();
                logOut();
            }

            else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    timerValue --;
                    createTimer();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    
        createTimer();
```

The above is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where is `initialTimervalue` is used ?

Comment: @Mohit Maroliya B17CS036 thanks, I had some issues pasting the code and forgot about this line.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with

let timerResetRequested = currentUser.sessionTimeout;

However, it looks like you are not interacting with the state at all which is why you are not seeing a state change.

Typically you would declare a state value:

```
const [timeValue, setTimeValue] = useState(0)
```

Then you could implement a function which increases that state value by clicking a button, for example.

then to reset the value of the timer you would implement a reset function which would reset the state value to zero.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: True, I fixed my post, apoligies for the confusion I caused.  This was supposed to be the initial value for the counter.